# Extracting specific h2 tag that contains different table information without duplication

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I'm building a screenscraper in C# using HtmlAgilityPack.

I am attempting to grab some specific text from a webpage involving dates. The site has a format as such - it has a date and day (h2) and then a table with the list of events happening that day. I am trying to get a list of each event including the date, so I need to extract the h2 and the table contents for that date. I have the second bit working fine - I'm extracting the event and other things associated with it.

```
HtmlNode nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='listings']");


            if (nodes != null)
            {

                foreach (HtmlNode gigs in nodes.SelectNodes("//table"))
                {
                    foreach (HtmlNode gigs2 in gigs.SelectNodes("//th"))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            results +=  gigs2.InnerText + ", " + gigs2.NextSibling.NextSibling.InnerText;
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e);
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
```

I'm at a loss how to take the h2 out, without using a foreach like above, all that I've come up with though just loops around taking each different h2 date out for every single listing, creating duplicates (and incorrect data).

There has to be another way that I just am not seeing. I'd appreciate any help pointing me in the right direction here - I'm just lost and code-blind at this stage so some fresh insight would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [predicates](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) and [axes](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp).

For example:

```
//h2[text()='some text']/following::table

//table[preceding::h2]
```

You can use combinations of these to isolate your desired table values rather than having to move through the result set.